# How to create Horizontal calender in flutter

Tags: flutter, calendar

I am not able to create the horizontal calender as shown in the image. I have tried few youtube video and still i am not able to find such calender anywhere. The current date must be highlighted with different colour. Please anyone provide me a code in fluttter or a proper tutorial if found anywhere [I want the code of the given picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpCft.png)

Comment: You forgot  to add the image.

Comment: Can CarouselSlider help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this package [calendar_timeline](https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_timeline) which seems quite similar with your requirements. Also in the readMe section you will find code implementation.